My laptop is not booting
Gave up waiting for root file system device.
Common problems:

Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

Check rootdelay= (did the system walt long enough?)


Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: is /dev)
ALERT! UUID=987b604b-e81f-47af-9674-261053bb736a does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)

Your systems's file-system table has a block device with UUID 987b604b-e81f-47af-9674-261053bb736a listed as a required device, but it could not be found - thus the system is following instructions encoded with mount rule & preventing boot. You've either removed (deleted?) a drive/partition that was setup as a required device by someone on your system with sudo rights, or you've had a hardware failure. You've provided no specifics, but an owner/user of the device has made a change OR hardware issue has occurred.

This question is similar to: Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
